How can I measure which messages are causing queue backups?
Consider the following multi-producer, multi-consumer system:

For simplicity, assume that we only have one queue
Messages are dequeued on a first-in-first-out basis
Oldest-message-pickup-latency has a SLO of X minutes
Any consumer can pick up any message
Consumers of messages can horizontally scale in accordance with increases in oldest-message-pickup-latency, but scaling takes a notable portion of the SLO (say, 20%)
Messages have both a type and parameters (think of a background job processing system)

Based on this, how would you be able to measure which messages are problematic when the SLO is violated?

pXX (percentile) duration is insufficient: a message could be slow to process but in low enough volume to not cause problems
count is insufficient: all of those messages could be processed very quickly
summed duration is insufficient: if the system is fully scaled, it could handle the burst fine

Are there other options or faults with my analysis?

One other option: Do you need to know which messages are problematic as an absolute, or might a statistical approach be sufficient? Would getting a sampling of the problematic messages with a chance some slip through, or having the chance to identify messages that aren'r problematic be acceptable?

I'm certainly intrigued!

It seems to me that messages aren't problematic, some sequence of messages and scaling is problematic. So you have to measure that and change your scaling triggers to match.
for example:
fast, slow, slow, fast

Might be fine;
fast, slow, fast, slow

Might fail your SLO because it doesn't trigger the scaling until task 3 which is too late
slow, slow, fast, fast

Might be fine, because the scaling is triggered on task 2.

Get a good estimate of how long each type of task takes to process.
Add a first stage that keeps track of the sum of that for the in flight messages
Record the current scaling and its events
Scale up earlier using a function of expected queue length and current/expected scale

Bonus points, log all the combinations and then use a synergy of AI and Blockchain to trigger the scaling!

One key aspect of the system which is not specified is the relative frequency of tasks. Are tasks short and frequent, or long and unusual?
If they are short and frequent, consider rate of change of summed duration. Summed duration what defines the amount of work required by the system, and thus how much of its capacity the messages are taking up. However that isn't directly what causes issues, since as you mentioned, the system can scale its capacity. Your issue is that the system scaling isn't perticuarly elastic, and you need to detect when the rate of increase in demand is higher than that scaling rate. This means that what you are looking for is message types where the amount of capacity consumed has changed suddenly, so rate of change of summed duration.
A simple way of measuring this is to measure it in fixed windows (say 1/10th of your scaling interval), and then calculate the average difference between subsequent windows.
However if the tasks are long and unusual, the issue is that its less meaningful to say a type of task is responsible, as opposed to the overall system is responsible. You need enough of a population of messages of any given type to establish an expected behavior. It might be worth grouping your messages in this case and only trying to identify the group.

This seems interesting, but I'm not sure how to think about it considering that "time spent processing a message" would be spread across several buckets. How do you calculate this?

It depends on the detail of the system and how much precision you need vs average task size. If the tasks are typically significantly smaller than the scaling time, and there are thus lots of them, just make the buckets large enough to catch enough tasks. If the tasks are big and counts low, then the question of which types of messages caused the scaling issue is less meaningful. As the proportion of messages within a window is as much an issue as the length of the task.

Some measurements to figure things out:

How long it takes to process each message.  Note, you will need to classify each type of message since there is 1 queue serving many different messages.
The volume of messages.  How many messages of each type.
Frequency, do the messages come in all at once, or is it a slow trickle throughout the day.
Message Visibility, that is when does your queue back up.

With those things in mind one should be able to see trends that cause scaling issues.  One thing to note, is sometimes scaling issues occur elsewhere.  For example, lets say each message interacts with a database.  Normally messages process very quickly, but at certain times of the day, database usages nears 100% and now message processing is effected.  So, the bottleneck may not be the message processing or volume, but elsewhere in the system.


Day 1: calculate your p99 (or p99.9 depending on volume or whatever)
Day 2: log all messages which have a processing time greater than whatever you calculated on Day 1


One term that I don't see mentioned here is 'throughput' and that is the core KPI when talking about queue-based systems.
Specifically, in this case, if you've missed this time, if a message arrives when at a queue depth of D, and your SLO is X minutes, your average throughput must be at least D/X messages per minute.  If you miss an SLO for that message, you must have had a lower throughput than that for the duration the message was on the queue.
This doesn't answer your question, of course, but the average required throughput is easy to calculate if you know the queue depth when the message arrived.  You then can look at the population of messages that were processed at a rate less than that.  Those are the messages that 'caused' the violation.
I put 'caused' in quotes because until you do that analysis, you can't really say that it was something about these messages that caused them to process too slowly, or even that they processed slowly at all.  It might simply be the case that there were more messages on the queue than you can possibly process in that SLO with the available resources.  Once upon a time, I was involved with a system where the target DB was unable to handle inserts at the rate the messages were being added to the source queue due to an index hotspot. I've also seen situations where the queue depth itself caused retrievals to become slower (due to, IMO, a poor design choice in the underlying queuing platform.)
In any event, once you've identified the 'offenders' you need to then try to understand if there's something about those messages that's special or if it's something related to volume, downstream systems or any other cause that is not specific to the messages.
